# Why does my returned structure change negative values to positive in c?

Tags: c, function, struct, negative-number

This creates a fraction and assigns negative signs accordingly. however, when i want to print out the whole numbers, numerators and denominators, the negative signs aren't passed into the the fractionPrint function. Therefore, only positive values are printed out.

```
struct fraction fractionCreate(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    struct fraction result;
    if (denominator == 0)
    {
        result.numerator = 0;
        result.denominator = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numerator*denominator <0)
        {

            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;

            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);
            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator/denominator)*-1;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = ((numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator)*-1;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = (numerator/GCD)*-1;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator*-1;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }

        if (numerator*denominator > 0)
        {
            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;
            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);

            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = numerator/denominator;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void fractionPrint(struct fraction f)
{
    if (f.numerator == 0 && f.denominator == 0)
    {
        printf("Divide by zero!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // There IS a whole number
        if (f.wholeNumber !=0)
        {
            int tempNumerator;
            if (f.numerator <0)
            {
                tempNumerator = f.numerator *-1;
            }
            //ONLY whole number
            if (tempNumerator == 1 && f.denominator ==1 )
            {
                printf("%d\n", f.wholeNumber);
            }
            //Mixed number
            else
            {
                printf("%d %d/%d\n", f.wholeNumber, f.numerator, f.denominator);
            }
        }
        //fraction only
        else
        {
            printf("%d/%d\n", f.numerator, f.denominator);
        }
    }

}

int main (void)
{
    struct fraction a, b, c, d, r, bad;

    a = fractionCreate (-5, -6);
    fractionPrint(a);
    b = fractionCreate (-10, 2);
    fractionPrint(b);
    c = fractionCreate (56, -160);
    fractionPrint(c);
    d = fractionCreate (-35, 150);
    fractionPrint(d);
    bad = fractionCreate (8, 0);
    fractionPrint(bad);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add the definition of `struct fraction`

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`; its `watch` command could be useful).

Comment: In fractionPrint the divide by zero check should only test the denominator, if it is zero then it doesn't matter what the numerator is.  Also, tempNumerator may be used uninitialized in the conditional test after the comment `//ONLY whole number` when f.numerator is >=0.

Comment: Do you know how to run the program in debug mode and trace it?  Have you done that? It should be easy to find the problem if you do so.  Besides, your program has too many redundant codes.  Similar codes should be gathered together (into functions perhaps).  For example, the GCD part should be a function, so that both place can call the same function. Please try to clean up/simplify your program before asking.

Comment: There are several online editors/compilers that you can use to test short programs and share online, for example, here is your program and my attempt at making it compile (that's how I found out about the potentially uninitialized tempNumerator - the compiler warned me). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0347a1902eba89b6

Answer (score 1):

The lost sign comes from:

```
result.wholeNumber = (numerator/denominator)*-1;
```

This is inside a block where `numerator * denominator < 0`, so this line always sets `wholeNumber` to be positive. Take out the `-1`.

Also, you have garbage in some other places because you don't initialize `wholeNumber` to `0` when it should be. And there is a potential problem due to the use of `fabs` and rounding that will show up when you try to store larger values; use integer negation instead of `fabs`.